# Python - duplicates in several lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a code which gives back 10 lists of numbers.

```
def my_random_list(l: list):
    return sorted(random.sample(list(set(l)), 6))


for _ in range(10):
    print(sorted(my_random_list([i for i in range(1, 43)])))
```

I need to count how many duplicates are there in this 10 lists.
How to do it in short and efficient way?

Comment: Can you share what you're trying to do with this code?

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: How about use `collections.Counter`. Counter is **bag** data structure of python. If you put all your lists into a Counter, you can get what elements are duplicate(greater than 2) and how many overlap.

Comment: You sort the same list twice, it's not needed

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm just trying to get my python skills solving interesting tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def my_random_list(l: list):
    return sorted(random.sample(list(set(l)), 6))

repeated = defaultdict(int)
for _ in range(10):
    rl = my_random_list([i for i in range(1, 43)])
    for x in rl:
        repeated[x] += 1
    print(sorted(rl))

repeated = {k:v for k,v in repeated.items() if v > 1}
print(repeated)
# {2: 2, 5: 3, 19: 4, 21: 4, 4: 3, 8: 2, 14: 2, 38: 3, 9: 3, 24: 2, 40: 3, 42: 2, 10: 2, 22: 3, 32: 2, 18: 3, 34: 2, 30: 2, 31: 3}
print(len(repeated.keys())) # how many duplicates
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/baca95387b)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list to a set, which automatically gets rid of duplicates. Then compare their size:

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,4]
print(len(l) - len(set(l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to find out the duplicates across the 10 lists, you can try the following -

```py
# Import Counter from collections 
In [11]: from collections import Counter

# Your definition of my_random_list
In [12]: def my_random_list(l: list):
    ...:     return sorted(random.sample(list(set(l)), 6))
    ...:

# Copying your version of creating 10 lists into a lists variable (calling the sorted() here is superfluous in my opinion)
In [13]: lists = [sorted(my_random_list([i for i in range(1, 43)])) for _ in range(10)]

# Count all the entries across all the 10 lists
In [14]: counter = Counter([])

# You can add multiple Counter instances to produce a "merged" Counter
In [15]: for l in lists:
    ...:     counter += Counter(l)

# Find the entries whose value exists more than once
In [16]: duplicates = [k for k,v in counter.items() if v > 1]

# Printing all the duplicate entries across the lists
In [17]: duplicates
Out[17]: [6, 16, 20, 37, 38, 2, 9, 29, 1, 18, 33, 3, 17, 19, 31, 15, 21, 42, 41, 11]

# Length of the duplicate list
In [18]: len(duplicates)
Out[18]: 20
```

You can read-up on `Counter` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

A statement of problem is not clear, I assume you want to calculate duplicates in concatenation of these 10 arrays. In this case you could use advantages of `numpy.unique`:

```
import random
import numpy as np
collection = [my_random_list(list(range(1, 43))) for i in range(10)]
conc = np.concatenate(collection) # concatenated list
items, cnt = np.unique(conc, return_counts=True) # sorted set of unique items and their counts
output = items[cnt>1] # items that appears more than once
```

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` and `itertools.chain` will be helpful.

```py
import random

source = [i for i in range(1, 43)]


def my_random_list():
    return sorted(random.sample(source, 6))


random_lists = [my_random_list() for _ in range(10)]
print(random_lists)
```

Here are 10 random lists(6 length for each).

```
>>> [[2, 4, 10, 18, 20, 30], [4, 12, 13, 19, 21, 27], [10, 11, 18, 26, 32, 33], [4, 11, 12, 17, 38, 42], [12, 22, 28, 38, 40, 41], [2, 11, 22, 30, 35, 36], [4, 6, 22, 24, 32, 34], [1, 3, 5, 25, 31, 33], [25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35], [12, 16, 28, 31, 37, 41]]
```

Then you can count it.

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain


counter = Counter(chain(*random_lists))
print(counter)
```

```
>>> Counter({4: 4, 12: 4, 11: 3, 32: 3, 33: 3, 22: 3, 31: 3, 2: 2, 10: 2, 18: 2, 30: 2, 38: 2, 28: 2, 41: 2, 35: 2, 25: 2, 20: 1, 13: 1, 19: 1, 21: 1, 27: 1, 26: 1, 17: 1, 42: 1, 40: 1, 36: 1, 6: 1, 24: 1, 34: 1, 1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 29: 1, 16: 1, 37: 1})
```

And filter the counter with comprehension.

```py
results = [k for k, v in counter.items() if v >= 2]
print(results)
```

```
>>> [2, 4, 10, 18, 30, 12, 11, 32, 33, 38, 22, 28, 41, 35, 25, 31]
```